# Propositional logic - wrong proof

Tags: logic, solution-verification, propositional-calculus

Given the propositions A, B and C, we assume that
\begin{equation}
(A\wedge B)\rightarrow C \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)
\end{equation}

I want to demonstrate the other way around implication

\begin{equation}
C \rightarrow (A\wedge B) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ (2)
\end{equation}
Obviously statement (1) doesn't necesssarely imply statement (2) anyway I started my strange reasoning
***Attempted proof***
by contraposition of the statement (1), we get
$$\neg C\rightarrow \neg A \vee \neg B \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ (3)$$

and the proposition (2) implies the following statement

$$\neg C\vee(A\wedge B) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ (4)$$
*Now, here comes my doubt!*

Combining statements (3) and (4) do I get the following statement?

$$(\neg A \vee \neg B)\vee(A\wedge B) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ (5)$$

the intuition suggests that writing $\neg C$ or $\neg A \vee \neg B$ doesn't change anything in statement (4) since the implication (3) holds by assumption.

If yes, since the statement (5) is always true therefore the statement 2 would be true as well.
Am I right? Am I wrong? 
Thank you!

Comment: It is possible that $(A \land B ) \to C$ is True and $C \to (A \land B)$ is False. Check it with truth table.

Comment: Aaah yes I am sorry I was reading the statement to be proved

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, I didn't state that (3) implies (4). My statement is that (4) can be written as (5) because of (3) ( which is true by assumption).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Long comment*

(1) holds by assumption and it is equivalent to (3) [and (4)].

We want to prove that also (2) holds.

What does it mean "combining statements (3) and (4)" ?

Conjunction ? If so, the "combination" implies (5): $(¬A∨¬B) ∨ (A∧B)$, and this formula is a *tautology*, i.e. always true.

Now we have the problem: "the statement (5) is always true therefore the statement (2) would be true as well." Why ?

We are trying to prove (2) and thus we are not entitled to assert that it is true.

The fact that (2) implies a True proposition does not mean that (2) is true: a tautology is implied by **every** proposition.

For example:

> $\varphi \vDash A \lor \lnot A$

is a valid inference for a formula $\varphi$ whatever.

---

The short answer is that $(A∧B) → C \nvDash C → (A∧B)$.

We can check it with truth-table: for $C$ True and $A$ False, we have that           (1) is True while (2) is False.